# IE custom fonts and jQuery animation - problem with font displaying

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, embedded-fonts

I use on my website some simple jQuery animation:

```
$("#content").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

And I'm using custom fonts from google in CSS (I load font from google server if that's important).

Without animation fonts looks fine, but when I wrote this jQuery code there is a problem. During the animation fonts render terrible and than, when animation end it looks fine again. Other browsers are fine ofc. I've tried to work with opacity and animate() in jQuery but than font was not coming back to good looking after animation so its even worst.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. I fixed it by putting a background color on the element that has the text in it. Hope that helps